# apache `httpd configcheck` says 'Useless use of AllowOverride in line 50.' , but there is no 'AllowOverride' in httpd.conf line 50?

Tags: apache-2.2

Running Apache httpd 2.2.

httpd is complaining about the following:

```
# service httpd configtest
[Tue Sep 13 10:10:14 2011] [warn] Useless use of AllowOverride in line 50.
```

But when I look at `httpd.conf`, there is no 'AllowOverride' parameter at line 50. This is what I see near line 50 (Lefthand column shows the line numbers):

```
 48 # ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
 49 # MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
 50 # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
 51 <IfModule prefork.c>
 52 StartServers      30
 53 MinSpareServers   20
 54 MaxSpareServers   50
```

So, how can I find this cause of 'Useless use of AllowOverride'?

Comment: Can you please post a full config or at least a part which contains all `AllowOverride`s?

Comment: It might not count comments as lines.

Comment: @Aaron And I bet it does not

Comment: some other file maybe?

Comment: `grep -lr "AllowOverride" /etc/httpd` (replace `/etc/httpd` to your actual server root)

Comment: Line 50 of an included config? (/etc/httpd/conf.d/)

Comment: @aaron: Correct. That is what I found. See my answer below.

Comment: Dang. I should have posted that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried stripping out comments, and whitespaces from `httpd.conf`. No luck.

It seems that Apache is referring to one of the files in my `conf.d` directory, which is `Include-ed` from `httpd.conf`.

In the file `conf.d/foo.conf` I see the following at line 50:

```
49 <Location ~ "/foo">
50     AllowOverride None
```

And this certainly does conflict with a use of AllowOverride earlier in httpd.conf (`AllowOverride None` for `Location \` ).

Very frustrating that this warning isn't more explicit.